# Create non-selectable text watermark in PDF

Tags: itext, watermark

After adding the text watermark and clicking on the PDF, Acrobat reader will display a **large blinking cursor** that looks more like a rendering artifact or start **selecting the watermark text**.

**Can the watermark text be made non-selectable?**

The watermark is a large "Draft" text under the existing content: using [c# itextsharp PDF creation with watermark on each page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372041/c-sharp-itextsharp-pdf-creation-with-watermark-on-each-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to make text non-selectable.

As an alternative to the large blinking cursor you may instead put an image of your watermark on the PDF.  This would instead give a small cross-hair cursor when you mouse over the watermark image.

Example:
[How can I insert an image with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583629/how-can-i-insert-an-image-with-itextsharp-in-an-existing-pdf)

Comment: Agree. @Brian, see this post for some hacks. http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Text-Selection-question-td2154502.html