# How do we use a PdfWriter of iTextSharp?

Tags: itext

If you do a google search you will find some code samples more or less like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, myIoStream);
```

And interestingly, most of the code samples don't use the writer object at all. So, what's the point of getting that handle? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do just `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, myIoStream);`

this will "create" the document using the stream.

When using `PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, myIoStream);`

we can use a lot of methods like `AddAnnotation()` that will be merged with the document or also call `.DirectContent` to add **images**, etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do yo uhave an idea how we can add a watermark to the pdf page?  Thanks.

Comment: Look for Stamper in ItextSharp.... Maybe this link can help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372041/c-sharp-itextsharp-pdf-creation-with-watermark-on-each-page